# Updating timestamps of related models

Tags: django, django-models, timestamp

I have the following two models:

```
class Blog(TimeStampedModel):
    summary = models.TextField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Entry(TimeStampedModel):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    text = models.TextField()
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, models.CASCADE, related_name='entries')
```

Both models sublass a common meta-model that defines a timestamp for when each model was last updated:

```
class TimeStampedModel(models.Model):
    last_changed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

This works fine when saving each model individually. However, in my use case, when an `Entry` is updated, it should also reflect in the update of the `last_changed` timestamp of the associated `Blog`.

Is there any easy way to tell Django to also bump the timestamps of related models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I admit that this is hacky, but you can override the `save` method of `Entry` model:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.blog.save()
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Oh, nice, I didn't know an empty `save()` bumps the timestamp as well. I thought it would be rejected as a noop since no changes were made to any of the fields. Thank you!

Comment: even if it doesn't, you should be able to add `self.blog.last_changed = now()` before saving the `Blog` instance